# Компонента TeeChart Java для Android

Tags: java, android, диаграммы, teechart

Кто работал с компонентой TeeChart Java для Android? Нужна помощь. Собственно нужно нарисовать диаграмму Ганнта, но не могу настроить эту самую диаграмму.
Отрисовываю ее так:

```
public class GantActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Series ser = new Gantt();
        TChart chart = new TChart(this);

        ser = chart.addSeries(gan);

        ser.add(SetGantt("2012-04-04 13:40"), SetGantt("2012-04-04 17:20"));
        ser.add(SetGantt("2012-04-05 12:00"), SetGantt("2012-04-05 13:00"));
        setContentView(chart);
    }

    // Тут мы преобразовываем строку в дату-время
    public double SetGantt(String dateBegin)
    {
        DateTime cal = (DateTime) DateTime.getToday();

        try {

            String str_date = dateBegin;
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            Date date1 = formatter.parse(str_date);

            cal.set(DateTime.DAY_OF_MONTH, date1.getDay());
            cal.set(DateTime.YEAR, date1.getYear());
            cal.set(DateTime.MONTH, date1.getMonth());
            cal.set(DateTime.HOUR_OF_DAY, date1.getHours());
            cal.set(DateTime.MINUTE, date1.getMinutes());

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        double ti = cal.toDouble();

        return ti;
    }

}
```

как сказано в справке:

> `int add(double start, double endDate, double y) 
>     Adds a new Gantt bar with start and end coordinates to the Series.`

Не пойму, что делаю не так... он мне рисует 2 полосы с непонятными датой/временем и видом типа long. Вместо double подставлял DateTime, но тоже ничего не принесло

Так же справка предлагает:

> `int   add(DateTime start, DateTime endDate, double y, Color color) 
>     Adds a new Gantt point to the series, at the start and endDate positions.
> int add(DateTime start, DateTime endDate, double y, java.lang.String text)           
> int add(DateTime start, DateTime endDate, double y, java.lang.String text, Color color)           
> void    add(double[] xValues, double[] yValues, boolean append)           
> int add(double x, double y) 
>     Adds a new point with specified x and y values.
> int add(double start, double endDate, double y) 
>     Adds a new Gantt bar with start and end coordinates to the Series.
> int add(double start, double endDate, double y, Color color) 
>     Adds a new Gantt bar with start and end coordinates and color.
> int add(double start, double endDate, double y, java.lang.String text) 
>     Adds a new Gantt bar with start and end coordinates and label.
> int add(double start, double endDate, double y, java.lang.String text, Color color) 
>     Adds a new Gantt bar with start and end coordinates, label and color.
> protected  void addSampleValues(int numValues) 
>     Adds random values to series.`

Причем, fillSampleValues() все заполняет красиво, но не могу узнать, какие параметры оно передает.

Comment: Неплохо бы видеть ссылку на документацию к библиотеке, которую Вы используете.

Comment: Вся дока тут http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/JavaDoc/com/steema/teechart/styles/Gantt.html#Gantt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего не знаю о `TeeChart`, тем не менее из самых общих соображений рискну спросить: зачем вы пишете `setContentView(chart);`?

По идее надо делать ведь так:

1. Создаем `main.xml` - ваш лэйаут, где есть некое заготовленное место для вставки `TChart` - скажем это некий `ViewGroup` под названием `myView`
2. Создаем `TChart` - примерно как у вас обозначено
3. Далее делаем в ваш лэйаут вставку `TChart` примерно как `myView.addView(chart)`

Вообще, если TeeChart это нормальная компонента, то по идее его можно сразу указать в main.xml и взять его через `chart=(TChart )findViewById()` и непосредственно добавлять ваши Гантты туда.

Comment: Нет, у меня трудность с самим формированием полосок ганттов. Не могу правильно вставить данные, либо не могу отформатировать рабочее пространство...

Comment: или хотя бы скажите как правильно сконвертить DateTime в дабл. DateTime наследует все от GregorianCalendar, но и имеет свои плюшки. Методом toDouble при построении полосок вылезает ошибка и прожка закрывается

Comment: DateTime в double как? Элементарно Ватсон: возьмите `(double )Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: не все так просто... не работает .getTimeInMillis()
нашел примерчик на забугорном сайте, там вот как ставится 

gantt.add(new DateTime(2003, 4, 2), new DateTime(2003, 4, 8), 2, "C");

а как в таком формате время проставить?